# Nested if statement - variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, if-statement

I know that the error may be in the if statement, but how am I suppose to write it so that it can work?

This program is suppose to know that if you have a "i" room, you have to pay for the nurse service but if you have a "d" room, you have to pay for the telephone and TV service.

//  PROCESSING

```
        if (room == "I") { // Begin if (room == "I")

            if (nurse == "X") { // begin if (nurse == "X")

                roomCost = (double)days * I_COST;
                TVCost = X_COST;
                phoneCost = X_COST;
                nurseCost = (double)days * X_COST;

            } // end if (nurse == "X")

            else if (nurse == "S"){ // begin else if (nurse == "S")

                roomCost = (double)days * I_COST;
                TVCost = X_COST;
                phoneCost = X_COST;
                nurseCost = (double)days * S_COST;

            } // end else if (nurse == "S")

            else if (nurse == "N") { // begin else if (nurse == "N")

                roomCost = (double)days * I_COST;
                TVCost = X_COST;
                phoneCost = X_COST;
                nurseCost = (double)days * N_COST;

            } // end else if (nurse == "N")

        }  // end if (room == "I")  



         if (room == "D") { // Begin  if (room == "D")

            if (TV == "V" && phone == "T") { // begin if (TV == "V" && phone == "T")

                roomCost = (double)days * D_COST;
                nurseCost = X_COST;
                TVCost = (double)days * V_COST;
                phoneCost = (double)days * T_COST;

            } // end if (TV == "V" && phone == "T")

            else if (TV == "V" && phone == "X") { // begin else if (TV == "V" && phone == "X")

                roomCost = (double)days * D_COST;
                nurseCost = X_COST;
                TVCost = (double)days * V_COST;
                phoneCost = X_COST;

            } // end else if (TV == "V" && phone == "X")

            else if (TV == "X" && phone == "T") { // begin else if (TV == "X" && phone == "T")

                roomCost = (double)days * D_COST;
                nurseCost = X_COST;
                TVCost = X_COST;
                phoneCost = (double)days * T_COST;

            } // end else if (TV == "V" && phone == "X")

            else if (TV == "X" && phone == "X") { // begin else if (TV == "X" && phone == "X")

                roomCost = (double)days * D_COST;
                nurseCost = X_COST;
                TVCost = X_COST;
                phoneCost = X_COST;

            } // end else if (TV == "X" && phone == "X")

        }  // end  if (room == "D") 

    // ********** OUTPUT **********

        // df1.format(double) ends up giving me two decimal places

        System.out.println("\nPatient ID     Days     Room       Nurse     TV Service     Telephone Service");
        System.out.println(patientID + "\t\t   " + days + "\t    $" + df1.format(roomCost) + "\t $" + df1.format(nurseCost) + "\t   $" + df1.format(TVCost) + "\t\t\t  $" + df1.format(phoneCost)); // ERROR VARIABLE ROOMCOST, NURSECOST, TVCOST AND PHONE COST MIGHT NOT HAVE BEEN INITALIZED
```

Comment: What is the error? What line is producing the error?

Comment: on which variable you are getting that variable is not initialized

Comment: I'm getting an error on the roomCost, nurseCost, TVCost and phoneCost on the last line.

Comment: It would be better if you show more of your code and show errors too.

Comment: Did you give them initial values? That is what it is complaining about. There can be a case where none of the if statements are true, so the variables don't get set.

Comment: initialize roomcost, nurseCost and TVCost by default value.

Comment: If you want to minimize the number of ifs, I suggest you create objects for room, nurse and service... you wouldn't need to do all these ifs... But you only need to initialize these values to their respective values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method for string equality check. `==` is good only in the case of primitives, but in case of objects it actually checks if the two variables refer to the same  object.

So your conditions should be like

```
if (room.equals("I")) {
```

---

For the warning, sounds like the variables `roomCost`, `nurseCost`, `TVCost` and `phoneCost` can start with a value of `0.0`, that way you can at least get rid of the warning.

Comment: I would even suggest If("I".equals(room)) { to prevent nullpointers

Answer (score 0):

If the `roomCost`, `nurseCost`, `TVCost` and `phoneCost` are declared inside the method, they won't be initialized by default. What I'm usually using is an initialization to a default value which I don't use.

for example, this won't work:

```
void foo()
{
 int i;
 int j = 7;

 if(j==7)
 {
  i=3;
 }
 else
 {
  i=2;
 }
  if (i==2)
 {
  System.out.println("it works");
 }
}
```

But if you'll also initialize `i` to `-1` for example, it will:

```
int i = -1;
```